# How to get JSON data from ajax request

Tags: python, django, ajax

I'm passing JSON back to my view from my html via ajax

within ajax call

```
            team_ids = ['1']
        
            //convert arrays into JSON
            var teamidarrayToString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, team_ids));
            var teamarrayJSON = JSON.parse(teamidarrayToString);

            var data = {
            teamarrayJSON: teamarrayJSON,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
            }

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/mypage/",  
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data) {
```

I'm not sure how to pickup teamarrayJSON within my views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def my_view(request):

    if request.is_ajax():

        team_ids = request.POST.get("teamarrayJSON")
        print(team_ids)
```

Print of team_ids is None. Can't figure out why. I printed (request.POST) and I can see the data.

```
<QueryDict: {'teamarrayJSON[0]': ['1'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['bZefleNuHLAa']}>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting to get on the server-side?

Answer (score 0):

Per your question, the result of printing request.POST is this:

```
<QueryDict: {'teamarrayJSON[0]': ['1'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['bZefleNuHLAa']}>
```

And in your code, you're trying to access 'teamarrayJSON':

```
team_ids = request.POST.get("teamarrayJSON")
```

In python dictionary.get() returns None if the key is not found and the value parameter is not specified. QueryDict is a dictionary-like object which has the .get() method that behaves the same as the builtin dict. So, your code is getting None because you're trying to access the key "teamarrayJSON", which doesn't exist. What exists however, is the key `teamarrayJSON[0]`. So you should get your data if you do this:

```
team_ids = request.POST.get("teamarrayJSON[0]")
```

Also, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve in this two lines:

```
var teamidarrayToString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, team_ids));
var teamarrayJSON = JSON.parse(teamidarrayToString);
```

You're using `Object.assign()` to convert `team_ids` array to JS object, then serializing it with `JSON.stringify()`, then using `JSON.parse()` to get a JS object again. These two lines are redundant and basically useless. You can pass your array directly to `data` when calling `.ajax()`, since `data` expects either Plain Object or string or array and it'll automatically serialize it according to the supplied settings. Check out [Jquery.ajax() api reference](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is some kind of bug in your client side js.
Just Console.log and verify that the teamarrayJSON
and try this :

```
teamarrayJSON = Object.assign({}, team_ids);
console.log(teamarrayJSON);
var data = {
        data: teamarrayJSON,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
        }
```

and check the output from your django view's request.POST